# Change Priority of ServiceProvider class

Tags: services

I have a module, `pod`. I am attempting to alter another service (`group.relation_handler.access_control.group_content_menu`), by implementing `Drupal\pod\PodServiceProvider::alter()`. This is working picked up, and I am able to swap out the backend class.

However, this alteration/swap is happening too late in the pipeline. For context, my alteration needs to happen before `Drupal\group\GroupServiceProvider::alter()` is called, as this class/callback alters the original class further, but my alteration comes later in the pipeline than this.

The problem is that `PodServiceProvider` is executed *after* `GroupServiceProvider`, and I need it to be executed before. I'm guessing this is because they are executed alphabetically.

So how can I change the priority of `PodServiceProvider` to be executed before `GroupServiceProvider`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are in control of the fully-qualified class name. It doesn't matter how often it is altered, the latest change counts. Which alterations your custom class contains depends on the base class you extend from.

Concerning the question. You can set priorities when adding compiler passes

```
class MymoduleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function register(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $container->addCompilerPass(new MyCompilerPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, 128);
  }
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#controlling-the-pass-ordering

When you are using the Drupal implementation of altering service definitions this is a predefined compiler pass [ModifyServiceDefinitionsPass](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DependencyInjection%21Compiler%21ModifyServiceDefinitionsPass.php/class/ModifyServiceDefinitionsPass) with default priority.

See also https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services#s-how-to-create-a-custom-compiler-pass

Comment: You are correct that the last item should take priority. However, GroupServiceProvider is creating a new service based on the service I need to alter. My alteration comes after GroupServiceProvider has already created that new service.

Comment: Unfortunately that stuff about compiler passes is beyond me, I have no idea what it even means. I don't know how Symfony works. I think I'm just going to create a system patch that hacks something and does what I need, I can't make it work through the APIs. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: I've answered the question title for people googling this topic. If the alphabetical order works for you, the rest looks like OOP. From what you describe in the question your class is a grandchild inheriting from parent (the service class of GroupServiceProvider) and grandparent (the original service class).

Comment: In the compiling stage, no services are created. This is at run-time when the service is used the first time and then only the class defined in the latest service definition is instantiated. The only requirement is that this class defines the methods in the service interface. You can do this from scratch, or extend an existing class and override one or more methods.

Comment: Thanks for the further information 4uk4 - I hope it can help someone else who gets it sometime in the future. I went an entirely different route altogether and instead set the menu to be an empty render array when the given criteria is met. Not ideal, but it met my requirement.